# 'nm' reports different sizes for variables of the same type. How do I find out their real size?

Tags: c, mingw, nm

I was trying to find out the addresses and sizes of variables in my program using `nm`, and I just realized a whole bunch of my variables are unexpectedly large. I made a following test file, "test.c":

```
static char test1 = 0;
static char test2 = 0;

char test_f(void)
{
    test1 = test2;
    return test2;
}

int main(void)
{
    return test_f();
}
```

Then I run the following commands:

```
gcc test.c
nm -C -S --size-sort a.exe | findstr /rc:"test"
```

And the output is

```
0000000140007040 0000000000000001 b test1
0000000140007041 000000000000000f b test2
0000000140001540 000000000000001a T test_f
```

I assume some sort of padding / alignment is at play here, but I don't understand why the padding became part of a symbol. Is there a way to produce a similar text log in which `test1` and `test2` would both have the size of 1?

Comment: [symbol sizes are computed as the difference between the value of the symbol and the value of the symbol with the next higher value](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html)

Comment: nm doesn't report sizes of variables; it reports sizes of symbols in the object file. Some of these symbols correspond to program variables contained within the space allocated for the symbol.

Answer (score 2):

> … I don't understand why the padding became part of a symbol.

The [`nm` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) says “The size is computed as the difference between the value of the symbol and the value of the symbol with the next higher value.” Therefore, if there is padding after variable A and before variable B, the padding will appear as part of the size of A.

In your example, `test1` was apparently immediately followed by `test2`, so the size of `test1` was computed as one byte. `test2` was not followed by any explicit symbol in its program section; the next “symbol” that `nm` used may have been the beginning of the next section or the first symbol in it. That next section has some alignment requirement, so there is unused space, also called padding, after `test2` and before the next section. So the difference between `test2` and the next “symbol” includes that padding, and it shows up in the “size” of `test2` as the man page states.

Comment: Is there a way to find out the symbol's real size, perhaps using the linker map or the debug info?

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why the padding became part of a symbol

According to the man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html

the ELF format records sizes for symbols, other formats (like EXE) will only report size as the interval from the start of this symbol to the start of the next one.

> Is there a way to produce a similar text log in which test1 and test2
> would both have the size of 1?

Do the same steps in Linux which uses ELF binaries.

```
0000000000004011 0000000000000001 b test1
0000000000004012 0000000000000001 b test2
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need this information for an .exe. Technically, I could build it for Linux, discover the variable sizes there, and merge that with offset information from `nm`, but that sounds complicated and error-prone. Is it possible to get variable sizes out of MinGW, perhaps via the linker map?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev doing just compilation without linking doesn't help, mingw producess COFF objects, which is, again, not ELF. I don't currently see an easy and practical possibility.

Comment: @Dmitry Grigoryev, Re "*I could build it for Linux, discover the variable sizes there*", That wouldn't work either. They could be different. In particular, `long` has a different size in Windows and in Linux on similar hardware.

Comment: @ikegami error-prone indeed!

Answer (score 0):

In the end, there seems to be no way to know symbol sizes in a PE without debug info. With debug info, one can extract it with `objdump -W a.exe` and then look up symbol type with `DW_AT_type`, then find out the size of that type with `DW_AT_byte_size`:

```
 <1><28ce>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <28cf>   DW_AT_name        : test1
    <28d5>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <28d6>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 3
    <28d7>   DW_AT_decl_column : 13
    <28d8>   DW_AT_type        : <0x28e6>
    <28dc>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 40 70 0 40 1 0 0 0     (DW_OP_addr: 140007040)
 <1><28e6>: Abbrev Number: 3 (DW_TAG_base_type)
    <28e7>   DW_AT_byte_size   : 1
    <28e8>   DW_AT_encoding    : 6  (signed char)
    <28e9>   DW_AT_name        : char
 <1><28ee>: Abbrev Number: 2 (DW_TAG_variable)
    <28ef>   DW_AT_name        : test2
    <28f5>   DW_AT_decl_file   : 1
    <28f6>   DW_AT_decl_line   : 4
    <28f7>   DW_AT_decl_column : 13
    <28f8>   DW_AT_type        : <0x28e6>
    <28fc>   DW_AT_location    : 9 byte block: 3 41 70 0 40 1 0 0 0     (DW_OP_addr: 140007041)
```